# What is the difference between $(window).load() & $(document).ready() function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

Can you give me an example that i could execute? I am a newbie in jQuery and would like to have this concept clear.

Answer (score 0):

For simple understanding we can define like that

> $(document).ready() will wrap DOM in `<body>...</body>` tag
>
> $(window).load() is parent of document which will wrap all DOM in
>   `<html>...</html>`tag